# Adding a user with multiple roles to WSO2 ESB using the UserAdmin service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have the following Soap request to add a user to WSO2 ESB using the UserAdmin service:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <mgt:addUser>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <mgt:userName>user</mgt:userName>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <mgt:password>password</mgt:password>
             <mgt:roles>everyone</mgt:roles>
    </mgt:addUser>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This works fine. I would now like to add a new user with multiple roles . Does anyone know how to do this?

Thx. nidkil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SOAPUI,  you can send an array of element by repeating the same element.  As follows you add multiple roles...

```
         <mgt:roles>role1</mgt:roles>
        <mgt:roles>role2</mgt:roles>
        <mgt:roles>role3</mgt:roles>
```

Comment: Thx Asela for the quick reply. Is there somewhere I can find more information about the admin services?

Comment: I guess not.. But you can see the UserAdmin WSDL and get some idea... Also there is a java client code to invoke this service which can be found here https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/wso2-samples/user-manager/user-admin-client-4.0.0/

Comment: I had discovered the WSDL option. The WSDL's do not define the types very well. The addUser action of the UserAdmin service for example does not provide any definition of the types. Not very helpfull if you have no clue :-) Is there anyway to findout more looking at the code that processes the Soap request? Where can it be fount?

Comment: yes..  there was an issue with UserAdmin WSDL in older version...  but in new version it has been fixed....  But WSO2ESB new version is not released yet..  May be in end of this week... You can get the RC1 pack and view the WSDL... I guess it contains the details...  https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/shafreen/20131128/wso2esb-4.8.0.zip